# Trying to execute script through tclsh + sftp

Tags: ssh, tcl, sftp, cisco, tclsh

For context i am trying to run a script that is hosted on a server made with TCL.

To run this script i log in a Cisco router and use the command:

```
tclsh tftp://[server_ip]/location/script.tcl
```

and it works over tftp, but when i try with sftp it does not work, says "No such file or directory", even tho i can copy the file and that works.

the command i use to cope the file is

```
copy sftp: flash:[server_ip]/location/script.tcl
```

so the router supports sftp.

and to try to run it i do exactly like tftp:

```
tclsh sftp://[server_ip]/location/script.tcl
```

to no avail.

So the copy works but executing the script does not work.

Any idea on how to fix this?

EDIT: I also tried SCP to no avail

Comment: This does not look right to me: How would your shell environment know how to resolve and read from a `tftp://`-prefixed path before invoking the commands (`copy`, `tclsh`). Do you have some virtual filesystem magic (FUSE?) underneath?

Comment: @mrcalvin I do invoke the commands copy and tclsh, also forgot to edit but i found the answear :) apparently is not  `tclsh sftp://[server_ip]/location/script.tcl`but rather `tclsh sftp://[server_ip]//location/script.tcl`... oh well, it blew my mind :)